# Implementation and interpretation of time-varying covariates/predictors and their interaction with time in linear mixed effects model

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, panel-data, time-varying-covariate

I have a longitudinal design, where we are interested in the relationship between clinical symptoms (continuous data) and brain data (also continuous) both measured over two timepoints. As we have a measure in each hemisphere of the brain, we also have a hemisphere factor. In addition, we have several covariates of non-interest.

From my reading, it seems that the correct way to model this would be:

```
lmer(BrainData ~ 1  +  Nuisance1 + Nuisance2 + Session * Hemisphere * SymptomChange + (1 + SymptomsAverage | ID ))
```

Where:  SymptomsAverage (random effect) is the Average for that individual, SymptomsChange (fixed effect) is the symptom data centred on the subjects average (See [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_you_include_time-varying_covariates_in_repeated_measures_mixed_effect_models) and [here](https://vrs.amsi.org.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/75/2016/03/Ligthart-Smith_VRS-Report.pdf) for rationale), and the covariates of no interest are denoted as Nuisance1 and Nuisance2. The data looks like this:

```
ID     Hemisphere session BrainData SymptomsChange SymptomsAverage Nuisance1 Nuisance2
<fct>  <fct>      <fct>       <dbl>          <dbl>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
028    L          E1           1.17           -0.5             8.5      62          99
028    R          E1           1.16           -0.5             8.5      62          99
028    L          E3           1.17            0.5             8.5      62          99
028    R          E3           1.15            0.5             8.5      62          99
029    L          E1           1.19            2               6        36.2       103
029    R          E1           1.13            2               6        36.2       103
029    L          E3           1.17           -2               6        36.2       103
029    R          E3           1.11           -2               6        36.2       103
030    L          E1           1.12            1.5             2.5      33         123
030    R          E1           1.10            1.5             2.5      33         123
```

**Q1** Is this the correct way of getting at my research question?

I find a significant interaction between Session and Symptom change. My initial thought was that this was my effect of interest - revealing if the brain measure was associated with symptoms in a time dependent manner. However, I’m now concerned it’s actually looking at a differential relationship between brain and symptoms at the two timepoints. Graphing the output with effect, supports this interpretation [to my eyes](https://www.rensvandeschoot.com/tutorials/lme4/). This differs from the question of whether symptom change is longitudinally associated with brain changes.

The alternative approach from my perspective, is simply to examine the main effect of SymptomsChange on the brain data. However, I’m interested in examining whether the trajectory of symptoms matches the trajectory of the brain data and it’s not 100% clear to me if this is capturing that. Without some temporal component, it just feels like I’m just checking for an association across both timepoints without taking into account the longitudinal nature of the study. Or is this longitudinal component implicit in the model in the way I'm not seeing?

**Q2** In my case, including random slopes for SymptomsAverage results in singular fit. If I follow [these] [3](https://www.rensvandeschoot.com/tutorials/lme4/) instructions, a likelihood-ratio test indicates that dropping these random slopes from the model does not affect it. Is it therefore ok to leave SymptomsAverage as a fixed effect, or does this fundamentally alter the interpretation of SymptomsChange?